I can't call another view with performSegue
I have an iOS application using storyboard and Swift. I'm trying to call a storyboard, and in the new view controller, I receive the error:
2024-04-29 15:40:46.156969-0300 MyQiwi[2464:54321] [Presentation] Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fcef133d800> on <UINavigationController: 0x7fceeeb1fa00> (from <UINavigationController: 0x7fceeeb1fa00>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
I'm forcing the code to run on the main thread.
Code:
extension TaxaLayoutFormViewController: BaseDelegate {
func onReceiveData(fromClass: AnyClass, param: Int, result: Bool, object: AnyObject?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {     
        if param == Param.Contact.TAXA_GET_CAMPO_TAXA_RESPONSE {
            self.dismissPage(nil)
            if result {
                self.executeOrder(response: object as! GetTaxasResponse)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
extension TaxaLayoutFormViewController {
func executeOrder(response: GetTaxasResponse)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.LIST_GENERIC, sender: nil)
}

}
The identifier used in performSegue is already linked in the storyboard. I tested by calling performSegue from viewDidLoad, and it worked correctly.
The same structure is used in other viewControllers and works correctly. I don't know why, in this storyboard, it returns the error.
enter image description here

The error says you are attempting to present a UINavigationController ... is that what you're expecting to do? In your executeOrder(...) func, who is self?

Exactly, the detail is that if I try to run performSegue() inside the viewDidLoad, it runs normally.

You didn't answer the second question... who is self when you call self.performSegue?

I believe it's: TaxaLayoutFormViewController.
I'll debug to make sure.

The Self is the TaxaLayoutFormViewController, I added an image showing the self.

You need to debug a little deeper. All that image shows is that self is an instance of TaxaLayoutFormViewController ... it doesn't show where that controller (and its view) is in the hierarchy. Is TaxaLayoutFormViewController a UINavigationController?
